# Keycloak Creating permission ticket keep facing (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)

Tags: json, keycloak

I want to create permission ticket following the instructions [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#creating-permission-ticket-2) but keep facing the below error while the body is correct:

> Uncaught server error:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> deserialize value of type
> `org.keycloak.representations.idm.authorization.PermissionTicketRepresentation`
> from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)

[Image of postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8VQL.png)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs, Permission ticket accepts a simple json object

```
{
       "resource": "{resource_id}",
       "requester": "{user_id}",
       "granted": true,
       "scopeName": "view"
     }
```

But In your postman request, you are passing an Array Of JSON object

```
[{
       "resource": "{resource_id}",
       "requester": "{user_id}",
       "granted": true,
       "scopeName": "view"
     }]
```

Just remove the '[' and ']' and send the request.

Comment: Hi thanks so much. That works. But My resource doesn't have any scope and I cannot remove scopeName key. What should I do? (keep facing     "error_description": "created permissions should have scope or scopeName"). Plus adding "" scopeName encounter "Scope [] is invalid"

Comment: The scopeName is the name of scopes that you have created already , you can create scope in each client